# select not initializing on filtered list

Tags: angularjs

The following piece of code works, except for one issue, the UI's drop-down doesn't initialize to the contents of the model.  The model is correctly initialized, the cookies are correctly saved/loaded.  And the rest of the code has been working just fine for a while.  I'm at a loss as to why the select won't initialize.

```js
app.controller("thisController",
    function ($scope, $http, $log, $rootScope, $location, $uibModal, $cookies) {
    
    $scope.saveCookie = function (key, value) {
        $cookies.putObject(key, value);
    }
    $scope.getCookie = function (key) {
        return $cookies.getObject(key);
    }
}
```

```html
    <select class="form-control"
            id="yearDropdown"
            ng-model="selectedYear"
            ng-init="selectedYear=getCookie('selectedYear')"
            ng-change="saveCookie('selectedYear', selectedYear)"
            ng-options="contract.ContractYear for contract in contractList
                      | orderBy:'ContractYear'
                      | unique:'ContractYear'">
        <option value="">All years</option>
    </select>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnMJw.jpg

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you share the part of the code where you retrieve the items that doesn't initialize. Also, by using `ng-init` for initialization, you're placing logic inside your template. This is considered an anti-pattern ([from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)), so you should move that logic to your controller instead.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I can add those methods!  I didn't include them cause they're definitely working from my testing because I verified them on the ng-model.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "the select won't initialize". Is the select empty? If that's the case, it would be helpful if you could share where the `contractList` variable comes from. Perhaps you can provide a Plunker, or similar, with a minimal example that shows the issue?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I mean that the DOM is not updating to the correct value, but the model is.  I added a picture demonstrating the in-practice issue alongside verification that the backing model is correctly initialized.  In the picture, the dropdown should have "2011", not "All years".

Comment: I'm heading to lunch shortly, but I'll be back afterwards if you have any other questions.  This is much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now and I have a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `<select>`-element isn't initialized with the value loaded from the cookie, is because it attempts to match the object *reference* of the initialized object, with the *references* to the contract objects in your `contractList`-variable. Since the initialized object comes from a cookie, it object reference doesn't match any of the objects in the `contractList`.

To solve this, you can specify to the `ngOptions`-directive, which attribute it should use to match objects to each other. You do this by appending `track by [expr]` to the expression.

So to fix your issue, your template should look somewhat like this:

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="yearDropdown"
        ng-model="selectedYear"
        ng-init="selectedYear=getCookie('selectedYear')"
        ng-change="saveCookie('selectedYear', selectedYear)"
        ng-options="contract.ContractYear for contract in contractList
                  | orderBy:'ContractYear'
                  | unique:'ContractYear'
                  track by contract.ContractYear">
    <option value="">All years</option>
</select>
```

If you have some other unique identifier on the `contract`-object (an id for instance), you should naturally opt to track by that instead.

*Note: I strongly recommend moving the `ngInit` logic to your controller.*

Comment: This solves the issue!  Thanks so much.  I'll probably move the ng-init logic based on your advice, now that the underlying issue is solved.